# Bootstrap generates identical values in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am running a non-parametric bootstrap in R from my data called nes2. Here is my code:

```
co.store <- NULL
for(i in 1:500){ #we do this 500 times
  dat.bs <- nes2[sample(c(1:nrow(nes2)),nrow(nes2),replace=T),] #sampling that I did before. New data set
  logit.bs <- glm(formula=bs.model,data=dat.bs,family=binomial(link="logit")) #run logit with new data set
  co <- coefficients(logit.bs) #get coeff
  co.store <- rbind(co.store,co) #store coeff, rbind instead of c in order to have a stack of numbers. 

}
```

The problem is that I get exactly identical coefficients for my new sample. 
I have tried several things, changing the formula putting in the whole model there (that is in formula instead of `bs.model` I tried putting 
`nes2$turnout~nes2$age+nes2$agesqrd+hs.edu+college.edu+nes2$white+nes2$income` which is the whole model) but it just won't work

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, make your example reproducible. We need `nes2` and `bs.model` to get a grasp of what's going on.

Comment: bs. model is bs.model <- NULL 
bs.model <- nes2$turnout~nes2$age+nes2$agesqrd+hs.edu+college.edu+nes2$white+nes2$income
bs.logit <- glm(formula=bs.model,data=nes2,family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(bs.logit)
coeff.bs <- coefficients(bs.logit) #storing the coefficients from the model. 
coeff.bs
coeff.predicted

Comment: bs. model is bs.model <- NULL 
bs.model <- nes2$turnout~nes2$age+nes2$agesqrd+hs.edu+college.edu+nes2$white+nes2$income
bs.logit <- glm(formula=bs.model,data=nes2,family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(bs.logit)
coeff.bs <- coefficients(bs.logit) #storing the coefficients from the model. 
coeff.bs
coeff.predicted  and the nes2 is a dataset that I gathered from Gary King's website: http://hdl.handle.net/1902.1/QTCABXZZRQ the article is this: Making the Most of Statistical Analyses:
Improving Interpretation and Presentation

Comment: Paula, can you edit your question to add the code from your comments please. It makes it much easier to see what is going on.

Comment: ps if you are using `nes2$` in your model it will not use the new bootstrap sample. `bs.model` should be like `bs.model <- turnout ~ age + agesqrd + hs.edu + college.edu + w‌​hite + income`